# Plus equals two variables returns isNan( ) = true when the variables themselves return isNan() = false - edited

Tags: javascript, timer, game-development, frame-rate

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm running into an issue I can't explain.  Two variables that are numbers, and isNaN() returns false for both, when added together using += the result is returning isNaN() = true.  Is there some nuance that I'm missing here?

The code is to set fps on frame rate in a side-scrolling game.  I'm trying to determine why this.frameTimer += deltaTime is equating to isNaN() = true, where the variables individually are equating to false.  The end goal is to get a valid number to compare against another variable.  Thanks for your help.

```
draw(context,deltaTime) {     
   if (this.frameTimer > this.frameInterval) {
       if (this.FrameX < this.maxFrame) { this.FrameX++
       this.frameTimer = 0 }
       else this.frameX = 0
   } else {
        this.frameTimer // isNaN(this.frameTimer) returns false
        deltaTime // isNaN(deltaTime) returns false
        this.frameTimer += deltaTime // isNaN(this.frameTimer) returns true
   }
   context.drawImage(this.image, this.width * this.frameX, this.height * this.frameY, this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
}
```

deltaTime is passed to the draw method, under the Player class, from an animate function in a separate module:

```
function animate(timeStamp) {
    const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime
    lastTime = timeStamp
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)
    gameObjects.forEach(object => {
        object.update()
        object.draw()
    })  
    player.update(input.lastKey)
    player.draw(ctx, deltaTime)
    drawStatusText(ctx, input, player)
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
}
```

The variables for frameTimer, fps and frameInterval are set in a Player class:

```
export class Player {
constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth - 200
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight
    this.states = [new StandingLeft(this), new StandingRight(this), new SittingLeft(this), new SittingRight(this), new RunningLeft(this), new RunningRight(this), new JumpingLeft(this), new JumpingRight(this), new FallingLeft(this), new FallingRight(this)]
    this.currentState = this.states[1]
    this.image = document.getElementById("player")
    this.width = 100
    this.height = 104
    this.x = this.gameWidth/2 - this.width/2
    this.y = gameHeight - this.height - 25
    this.vy = 0 
    this.weight = 0.5
    this.frameX = 0
    this.frameY = 0
    this.maxFrame = 0
    this.speed = 0
    this.maxSpeed = 5
    this.fps = 15
    this.frameTimer = 0
    this.frameInterval = 1000/this.fps
}
```

Comment: What are the values of  that props?

Comment: Please make a working snippet in your question that shows your issue.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the exact values for those fields. Try logging their types: eg, `console.log(this.frameTimer, typeof this.frameTimer)` and see if they both come back as `number`. The behavior of `isNaN` can be surprising, since it converts its argument to Number before checking if it is `NaN`. It's not hard to find two values `a` and `b` where `isNaN` is `false` for each, but where `isNan(a + b)` is `true`. For example, `a = false` and `b = ""`.

Comment: This post has been edited for clarity.  Both variables return typeof() = number.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing keyword **this** before .deltaTime, the parameter may not have been given a value and thats why its giving `true`, here is an expample:

```
draw(a, b){
        console.log(isNaN(b)) //Return true if b is left without value
        console.log(isNaN(this.c)) //Returns true if this.c is undefined too
    }
```

Your mistake is right here:

```
draw(context,deltaTime) {     
   if (this.frameTimer > this.frameInterval) {
       if (this.FrameX < this.maxFrame) { this.FrameX++
       this.frameTimer = 0 }
       else this.frameX = 0
   } else {
        this.frameTimer // isNaN(this.frameTimer) returns false
        this.deltaTime // isNaN(this.deltaTime) returns false
        this.frameTimer += ------> deltaTime <-------// isNaN(this.frameTimer)returns true
   }
   context.drawImage(this.image, this.width * this.frameX, this.height * this.frameY, this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
}
```

Comment: This post has been edited for clarity.

Comment: Check if `this.frameTimer` & `deltaTime` have a value, maybe one of them is null

Comment: Hello, and thanks.  Both do appear to have valid values.  this.frameTimer, when logged to the console alone, has a value of 0, and deltaTime has a varying value of ~16.000.  I did notice that, when checking the typeof for deltaTime, which is being passed to the draw method from an animate function in a different module, the initial reading is "undefined" after which point it turns to "number".  I'm not sure why that would occur.  The "undefined" initial reading only occurs in the imported player module, and not the animate function from which the argument is passed.